# composing an async function with unknown number of arguments and return the correct type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wanted to do a helper function that wraps an existing async function with a variable number of arguments, so that I can call it as such:

```
const submit = wrapLoading(async (values: string[]) {
  // await something with values
  return true
})

submit(['1', '2'])  // Call it
```

My implementation is something like this. Can anyone tell me why the return type is always `Promise<any>`, even though `F` in the case above, is returning a `Promise<boolean>`

```
export const wrapLoading = <F extends(...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(
  process: F
) => async (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
  isLoading.value = true
  const result = await process(...args)
  isLoading.value = false
  return result
}
```

If, instead, I use another argument to specify the return type, it will always return a `Promise<unknown>` instead. I really don't see how to solve this whole thing elegantly.

```
export const wrapLoading = <R, F extends(...args: any[]) => Promise<R>>(
  process: F
) => async (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
  isLoading.value = true
  const result = await process(...args)
  isLoading.value = false
  return result
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: TypeScript is much better at manipulating generic argument/return types than it is with manipulating generic function types.  If you switch to that, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDeajm), you get the desired behavior.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can infer the type using the utility types `ReturnType` & `Awaited` !

```
let isLoading: {value: boolean};

export const wrapLoading = <F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(
  process: F
) => async (...args: Parameters<F>): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<F>>> => {
  isLoading.value = true
  const result = await process(...args)
  isLoading.value = false
  return result
}

const submit = wrapLoading(async (values: string[]) => {
  // await something with values
  return true
})

const foo = submit(['1', '2'])  // Call it
    //^?  Promise<boolean>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAGwpgLgBAlgzgGQPYEMAmMB2BzAXFAbwDcUQBXMfAIySXBUwF8BuYYMADwAckAnaAMZJMcaAHdeKLsnRZsUALxQAPADEonCGExo4UABQA6Yyl7Y4%20BgE8A2gF0AlIoB8UAAq8kAW3hhl152d9YCgoLk8BMDgLKFVgJwVXFDgrTAEDY0NTc3w3UxQvSDBeODVnB1zPHzg-AEExFBgtNGUAJUgyXkwAFSsuP1VA10TCENhEVAwcQxJyMEUoCF4KMaERaF4oshBoJRQGprCIqLgjEzM4BzH4GSnsGdIKBYAzUhqxzYhOzChNuG2IMBGGw1qIoP8qD5dlAJFJbnJ9MlUul9LMKDFRLw5PYEq4CGMAPQEqD7RrQODeSAACzkMKaVKgaKiHw6XUWyzAQKuwFB0GetAWEKh%20hsAHIAIyigA0UFFACZRY5QkSoABhUggWCA0LKgkAPQA-EA)

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution.
Not obvious indeed, when you are a newcomer.
It seems that Typescript is somewhat flawed in this regard. So you need to use the utilities to reflect the actual function type. Like ReturnType<>, Parameters<>, etc. and not rely on the generic type.

Comment: You do not need to use utilities, as I showed in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDeajm).  I'm happy to write up an answer anyway even though you've accepted this one (or maybe @MatthieuRiegler wants to edit this to mention this approach); let me know what you want to see.